# Create index on EXISTS condition

Tags: postgresql, indexing, query-performance

My table structure:

```
table_a(id, company_id, approval_status, is_locked)
table_b(tba_id, status)
```

My Query:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) filter (WHERE approval_status = 2 
AND is_locked = true AND EXISTS 
(SELECT 1 from table_b WHERE table_b.tba_id = table_a.id 
AND table_b.status = 2) 
FROM table_a
GROUP BY company_id
```

I currently have the following index, but the performance is still slow:

```
CREATE INDEX multiple_filter_index ON table_a (approval_status, is_locked)
```

Can the performance of this query be improved by adding better indexes?

Here is the Query plan:

```
HashAggregate  (cost=463013.07..463013.10 rows=2 width=11) (actual time=47632.476..47632.476 rows=2 loops=1)
  Group Key: table_a.company_id
  ->  Seq Scan on table_a  (cost=0.00..3064.62 rows=100062 width=11) (actual time=0.003..23.326 rows=100062 loops=1)
  SubPlan 1
    ->  Seq Scan on table_b  (cost=0.00..477.27 rows=104 width=0) (actual time=1.430..1.430 rows=0 loops=33144)
          Filter: ((tba_id = table_a.id) AND (status = 2))
          Rows Removed by Filter: 17411
  SubPlan 2
    ->  Seq Scan on table_b table_b_1  (cost=0.00..433.73 rows=5820 width=4) (never executed)
          Filter: (status = 2)
Planning time: 0.902 ms
Execution time: 47632.565 ms
```

Comment: You may try modifying your index by adding columns which appear in the `EXISTS` clause, which is really a subquery.  You should look at the explain plan to see where the bottleneck might be exactly.

Comment: Can you give me more details? Here is the part in the explain plan take most time: HashAggregate  (cost=463013.07..463013.09 rows=2 width=11)

Comment: You should run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and include the plan in your question, assuming it would fit reasonably well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current execution plan shows that Postgres is not using the index you defined at all.  Rather, it is just doing two sequential scans of each table, which won't be particularly efficient if those tables are large.

First, AFAIK your query will be executed the same as this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM table_a
WHERE
    approval_status = 2 AND
    is_locked = true AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 from table_b WHERE table_b.tba_id = table_a.id AND table_b.status = 2)
GROUP BY company_id;
```

That is to say, the Postgres filter will really just behave the same as if that logic were in a formal `WHERE` clause.

I would suggest creating an index on *each* of the two tables:

```
CREATE INDEX table_a_idx ON table_a (approval_status, is_locked, company_id);
CREATE INDEX table_b_idx ON table_b (status, tba_id);
```

The reasoning for the `table_a_idx` index is that we want to eliminate as many records as possible using the `approval_status` and `is_locked` filters.  I also included the `company_id` in this index, to cover the `GROUP BY` column, hopefully avoiding the need to do an additional disk read after traversing the index.

The `table_b_idx` exists to speed up the `EXISTS` clause of your query.

I would also recommend that you use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving some filtering logic into a join

```
SELECT
    company_id
  , COUNT(CASE
        WHEN approval_status = 2 AND
            is_locked = TRUE AND
            b.tba_id IS NOT NULL
        THEN id
    END)
FROM table_a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT tba_id 
    FROM table_b
    ) b on b.tba_id = table_a.id
GROUP BY
    company_id
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this query is 3x slower than my original.

Comment: ok, so a lateral join was unhelpful - sorry.  I've amended my answer but your best bet is to provide the explain plan as requested above.

Comment: Why would you expect a left join to be more efficient than an exists clause which uses the same logic?